# Syntax for nextval() in pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

What is the correct syntax for sequence functions like nextcal() or setval() in pgAdmin?
Select nextval("seq_name")
PostgreSQL version = 15.2

I tried all syntax Google found in the net, but always got en error.

Comment: There is only one manual for each PostgreSQL version, you could have tried that:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html
SELECT setval('myseq', 42);           -- Next nextval will return 43

Comment: This `nextval("seq_name")` is correct. What is the error you are getting? **Add error to question as text**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is `nextval('seq_name')`. Surrounding the name with `"` instead of `'` makes it an identifier which is incompatible with the function's signature.

Comment: Yes, nextval('schema."seq_name"') works. You must use ' and ".